# How pull JSON data using foreach loop in php

Tags: php, json

I have a code for debtor's lustration (executory), but I'm not familiar with the structure of the data. I'm not able to put it record by record in a nice table **(even after I read a few threads here)**. Can you help me with this, please?

My code for fetch json data is:

```
$urlSearch = 'https://www.ceecr.cz/api/v4/search';
                $apiToken3 = 'token=secret_token';
                $nameSearch = 'name=Michael';
                $birthSearch = 'birth=1901-01-01';
                $personSearch = 'person=F';
                $request_url3 = $urlSearch . '?' . $apiToken3 . '&' . $nameSearch . '&' . $birthSearch . '&' . $personSearch;

                $curl3 = curl_init($request_url3);

                curl_setopt($curl3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl3, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
                    'X-RapidAPI-Host: ceecr.cz',
                    'X-RapidAPI-Key: ae8wie9Toez0',
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                ]);

                echo $response3 = curl_exec($curl3);
                curl_close($curl3);

                $vysledky =  json_decode($response3, true);
```

and now I get this json response

```
{"status":200,"data":[{"subjects":[{"subject_id":505896577,"typ_osoby":"F","jmeno":"Michael","datum_narozeni":"1901-01-01","ico":null,"ic":null,"adresa":"Prague","adm":18327991,"identification":{"type":"rc","hash":"LwKvzy4"}}],"subject_count":1,"ex_cislo":"018EX5581\/19","cause_id":"Exk6w3Q","datetime_zalozeni":"2020-12-01","datetime_upravy":"2020-12-01","date_vydano":"2019-10-10","posledni_uprava":"Pravomocn\u00e1 exekuce","datum_soudniho_narizeni":"2019-10-10T00:00:00+02:00"},{"subjects":[{"subject_id":505877637,"typ_osoby":"F","jmeno":"Michael","datum_narozeni":"1901-01-01","ico":null,"ic":null,"adresa":"Prague","adm":18327991,"identification":{"type":"rc","hash":"LwKvzy4"}}],"subject_count":1,"ex_cislo":"018EX6655\/16","cause_id":"xJWLRz9","datetime_zalozeni":"2020-12-01","datetime_upravy":"2020-12-01","date_vydano":"2016-07-18","posledni_uprava":"Pravomocn\u00e1 exekuce","datum_soudniho_narizeni":"2016-07-18T00:00:00+02:00"},{"subjects":[{"subject_id":505541695,"typ_osoby":"F","jmeno":"Michael","datum_narozeni":"1901-01-01","ico":null,"ic":null,"adresa":"Prague","adm":18327991,"identification":{"type":"rc","hash":"LwKvzy4"}}],"subject_count":1,"ex_cislo":"203EX52157\/12","cause_id":"y4oWDa3","datetime_zalozeni":"2020-10-15","datetime_upravy":"2020-10-15","date_vydano":"2012-11-02","posledni_uprava":"Pravomocn\u00e1 exekuce","datum_soudniho_narizeni":"2012-11-02T00:00:00+01:00"},{"subjects":[{"subject_id":503487104,"typ_osoby":"F","jmeno":"Michael","datum_narozeni":"1901-01-01","ico":null,"ic":null,"adresa":"Prague","adm":18327991,"identification":{"type":"rc","hash":"LwKvzy4"}}],"subject_count":1,"ex_cislo":"106EX9853\/12","cause_id":"6qZn7e4","datetime_zalozeni":"2020-09-07","datetime_upravy":"2020-09-07","date_vydano":"2013-01-02","posledni_uprava":"Pravomocn\u00e1 exekuce","datum_soudniho_narizeni":"2013-01-02T00:00:00+01:00"},{"subjects":[{"subject_id":503206676,"typ_osoby":"F","jmeno":"Michael","datum_narozeni":"1901-01-01","ico":null,"ic":null,"adresa":"Prague","adm":18327991,"identification":{"type":"rc","hash":"LwKvzy4"}}],"subject_count":1,"ex_cislo":"220EX14857\/12","cause_id":"XD9ePEr","datetime_zalozeni":"2020-09-06","datetime_upravy":"2020-09-06","date_vydano":"2012-12-05","posledni_uprava":"Pravomocn\u00e1 exekuce","datum_soudniho_narizeni":"2012-12-05T00:00:00+01:00"},{"subjects":[{"subject_id":502979099,"typ_osoby":"F","jmeno":"Michael","datum_narozeni":"1901-01-01","ico":null,"ic":null,"adresa":"Prague","adm":18327991,"identification":{"type":"rc","hash":"LwKvzy4"}}],"subject_count":1,"ex_cislo":"067EX403926\/11","cause_id":"nX4o9Lg","datetime_zalozeni":"2020-09-05","datetime_upravy":"2020-09-05","date_vydano":"2011-11-30","posledni_uprava":"Pravomocn\u00e1 exekuce","datum_soudniho_narizeni":"2011-11-30T00:00:00+01:00"},{"subjects":[{"subject_id":502978222,"typ_osoby":"F","jmeno":"Michael","datum_narozeni":"1901-01-01","ico":null,"ic":null,"adresa":"Prague","adm":18327991,"identification":{"type":"rc","hash":"LwKvzy4"}}],"subject_count":1,"ex_cislo":"067EX403261\/11","cause_id":"Go2Kz2p","datetime_zalozeni":"2020-09-05","datetime_upravy":"2020-09-05","date_vydano":"2012-09-26","posledni_uprava":"Pravomocn\u00e1 exekuce","datum_soudniho_narizeni":"2012-09-26T00:00:00+02:00"},{"subjects":[{"subject_id":502975505,"typ_osoby":"F","jmeno":"Michael","datum_narozeni":"1901-01-01","ico":null,"ic":null,"adresa":"Prague","adm":18327991,"identification":{"type":"rc","hash":"LwKvzy4"}}],"subject_count":1,"ex_cislo":"067EX401066\/11","cause_id":"OgOeREO","datetime_zalozeni":"2020-09-05","datetime_upravy":"2020-09-05","date_vydano":"2013-04-23","posledni_uprava":"Pravomocn\u00e1 exekuce","datum_soudniho_narizeni":"2013-04-23T00:00:00+02:00"},{"subjects":[{"subject_id":501985823,"typ_osoby":"F","jmeno":"Michael","datum_narozeni":"1901-01-01","ico":null,"ic":null,"adresa":"Prague","adm":18327991,"identification":{"type":"rc","hash":"LwKvzy4"}}],"subject_count":1,"ex_cislo":"195EX879\/19","cause_id":"1x4JmQD","datetime_zalozeni":"2020-07-16","datetime_upravy":"2020-07-16","date_vydano":"2019-06-25","posledni_uprava":"Pravomocn\u00e1 exekuce","datum_soudniho_narizeni":"2019-06-25T00:00:00+02:00"},{"subjects":[{"subject_id":501267412,"typ_osoby":"F","jmeno":"Michael","datum_narozeni":"1901-01-01","ico":null,"ic":null,"adresa":"Prague","adm":18327991,"identification":{"type":"rc","hash":"LwKvzy4"}}],"subject_count":1,"ex_cislo":"070EX921\/19","cause_id":"GoGXjyw","datetime_zalozeni":"2020-07-02","datetime_upravy":"2020-07-02","date_vydano":"2019-06-18","posledni_uprava":"Pravomocn\u00e1 exekuce","datum_soudniho_narizeni":"2019-06-18T00:00:00+02:00"},{"subjects":[{"subject_id":501158391,"typ_osoby":"F","jmeno":"Michael","datum_narozeni":"1901-01-01","ico":null,"ic":null,"adresa":"Prague","adm":18327991,"identification":{"type":"rc","hash":"LwKvzy4"}}],"subject_count":1,"ex_cislo":"017EX1279\/14","cause_id":"0nJB0Dk","datetime_zalozeni":"2020-07-01","datetime_upravy":"2020-07-01","date_vydano":"2014-06-23","posledni_uprava":"Pravomocn\u00e1 exekuce","datum_soudniho_narizeni":"2014-06-23T00:00:00+02:00"},{"subjects":[{"subject_id":500292883,"typ_osoby":"F","jmeno":"Michael","datum_narozeni":"1901-01-01","ico":null,"ic":null,"adresa":"Ji\u0159\u00edho n\u00e1m\u011bst\u00ed 20\/1, 290 01 Pod\u011bbrady","adm":18327991,"identification":{"type":"rc","hash":"LwKvzy4"}}],"subject_count":1,"ex_cislo":"099EX2526\/19","cause_id":"K4gEm4p","datetime_zalozeni":"2019-10-24","datetime_upravy":"2019-10-29","date_vydano":"2019-08-07","posledni_uprava":"Pravomocn\u00e1 exekuce","datum_soudniho_narizeni":"2019-08-07T00:00:00+02:00"},{"subjects":[{"subject_id":500990582,"typ_osoby":"F","jmeno":"Michael","datum_narozeni":"1901-01-01","ico":null,"ic":null,"adresa":"Prague","adm":18327991,"identification":{"type":"rc","hash":"LwKvzy4"}}],"subject_count":2,"ex_cislo":"070EX4010\/12","cause_id":"b57Rm5x","datetime_zalozeni":"2016-01-08","datetime_upravy":"2016-01-08","date_vydano":"2012-09-05","posledni_uprava":"Pravomocn\u00e1 exekuce","datum_soudniho_narizeni":"2012-09-05T00:00:00+02:00"},{"subjects":[{"subject_id":91226235,"typ_osoby":"F","jmeno":"Michael","datum_narozeni":"1901-01-01","ico":null,"ic":null,"adresa":"Prague","adm":18327991,"identification":{"type":"rc","hash":"LwKvzy4"}}],"subject_count":1,"ex_cislo":"023EX362\/14","cause_id":"ROW4Ky","datetime_zalozeni":"2014-03-18","datetime_upravy":"2014-09-24","date_vydano":"2014-03-31","posledni_uprava":"Pravomocn\u00e1 exekuce","datum_soudniho_narizeni":"2014-03-31T00:00:00+02:00"},{"subjects":[{"subject_id":51215496,"typ_osoby":"F","jmeno":"Michael","datum_narozeni":"1901-01-01","ico":null,"ic":null,"adresa":"Prague","adm":18327991,"identification":{"type":"rc","hash":"LwKvzy4"}}],"subject_count":1,"ex_cislo":"081EX31382\/12","cause_id":"3e2qz5","datetime_zalozeni":"2013-03-18","datetime_upravy":"2013-03-18","date_vydano":"2012-10-22","posledni_uprava":"Pravomocn\u00e1 exekuce","datum_soudniho_narizeni":"2012-10-22T00:00:00+02:00"}],"dataSource":"regular","info":{"search":{"type":"name|birthdate","query":"Michael|1901-01-01"},"zbyva_dotazu":{"placenych":11,"free":null},"zbyvajici_kredit":660,"cena":{"zaplaceno":"60 CZK","kredit":660},"debug":{"found":15}}}
```

For better readability, I recommend http://array.include-once.org/

I can't list each record separately, the result should look something like this:
[image]

I beg you very much, save my life and my nerves. Thank you very much

Comment: What  doesn't work? Where's the problem? Creating HTML tables? `foreach`ing the data? What have you tried so far?

Comment: btw, It doesn't have to list all the values for me, but just subjects.subject_id, subjects.typ_osoby, subjects.name, I can add the rest of the data myself according to the enclosed code

Comment: @brombeer both :) I try this for example https://pastebin.com/YCqJ19RV

Comment: @brombeer It's hard for me and I would need specific code for my situation to understand it. My mistake was learning the copy and paste style :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as easy as below

```php
$data = empty($vysledky['data']) ? [] : $vysledky['data'];
foreach ($data as $subject_collection) {
   if (empty($subject_collection['subjects'])) continue;
   foreach ($subject_collection['subjects'] as $subject) {
       // you can now pull out data such as subject_id etc.
       var_dump($subject);
   }
}
```

See [repl.it](https://replit.com/@alexmk92/GigaSecondaryClients#main.php) for reference

Comment: Oh, you are my god :) I am finish, thank you very very much ! :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help :)

Comment: @MichaelGrznár If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted

Comment: @brombeer done. I forgot, I am sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, I think below code should work -

```
$data = json_decode($vysledky->data, true);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
   $subject_id = $value['subjects'][0]['subject_id]; //as subject_id in within another array
   $ex_cislo = $value['subjects']['ex_cislo']; //ex_cislo is attribute of $value array
}
```

Comment: I've tried something similar, but I don't know how to get those values, like "subject_id", "ex_number", "datetime_zalozeni" etc. Each record on one row in the table. Would you please add yours // iterate every row as table column

Comment: @MichaelGrznár - I have modified the code, you can check

Comment: Thank you very much for help :) it will help me in the future, but i needed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69787405/10458656)